# GnuTLS: TLS connection was non-properly terminated - error after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, git, redmine, gnutls

I am using ubuntu server 16.04.  I just upgraded this morning.  This command which is part of the redmine upgrade generates a GnuTLS error.  I have searched for solutions online but have found none.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
**bundle install --gemfile=/opt/redmine/redmine/Gemfile**

Fetching https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/sysadmin has failed.error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (3/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/sysadmin has failed.error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

Retrying `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (4/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/sysadmin has failed.error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

**Git error: command `git clone 'https://github.com/jbox-web/gitolite-rugged.git' "/home/sysadmin/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/cache/bundler/git/gitolite-rugged-f96eae3bf467935eea22ec876625e07825442454" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory
/home/sysadmin has failed.***
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an SSL issue (did you perhaps change certificates, or update crypto libraries during the upgrade)?

You can try reinstalling git, or, failing that, you can rebuild git from source using a different crypto backend. You can reference the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529639/gnutls-recv-error-110-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated).